# Get selected value from jqueryui autocomplete combobox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, combobox

I'm trying to get selected value from [jqueryui autocomplete combobox](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox).

Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/69akn/).

I have added below code to get selected value. but it is not worked.

```
$( "#combobox" ).autocomplete({
   select: function(event, ui) { 
       alert($(ui).val());
   }
});
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all in a "normal" autocomplete you would get the value of the selected item by doing `ui.item.value`.
In your case this doesn't work. Perhaps because the select function gets overridden.

Instead alert the value in your `autoCompleteSelect` function.

```
this._on(this.input, {
    autocompleteselect: function (event, ui) {
        /* THIS IS NEW */
        alert(ui.item.value);
        ui.item.option.selected = true;
        this._trigger("select", event, {
            item: ui.item.option
        });
}
```

If you are curious what other options you could get in this function just do a `console.log(ui)` in it and open your console to see other options.
All in all you don't even need to call the autocomplete widget anymore.

<kbd>[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/69akn/6/)</kbd>

Comment: If you get option value not the text you can get via `ui.item.option.value`

Answer (score 6):

Here is  the working fiddle for the solution to your problem:
[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69akn/10/)

```
 $( "#combobox" ).combobox({
      select: function( event, ui ) {
      alert(ui.item.value);
      }
      });
```

Just access the value variable of item in ui, you will get the required value of selected option.Just a small change is required in your code and its fixed.

Comment: ui.item.value is the text between `<option value="x">' and '</option>', *ui.item.option.value* is the actual value

Answer (score 0):

First set id of textbox and then get value of that textbox and match it with text of option of dropdown, if option's text match then get its value. you can see example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bhargav3vedi/15nnru0d/) in jsfiddle

```
this.input = $("<input>")
     .appendTo(this.wrapper)
     .val(value)
     .attr('placeholder', "Enter Type...")
     .attr("title", "")

     // Set Id of Input Type Text    

     .attr('id', 'Mach')
     .addClass("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left")
     .autocomplete({
     delay: 0,
     minLength: 0,
     source: $.proxy(this, "_source")
     })
```